# scrape html without id in vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to get month-to-date and year-to-date return values from the website
http://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-oil-gas-exploration-production-select-industry-index
into an Excel spreadsheet using VBA. The problem is that there is no "id= " in the code of the page, which I understand would make this process a lot simpler. There is also the matter of which time period (year-to-date or month-to-date) is visible, but I'd be happy with scraping just the MTD values for now.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Get_Change()

'attempting to scrape Barclay's website

Dim appIE As Object
Dim MyVar As String


Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "http://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-oil-gas-exploration-production-select-industry-index"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Range("A1").Value = "Working..."
Loop
Set TDelements = appIE.document.getElementsbyClassName("performance-chart-table")

For Each TDelement In TDelements
    If TDelement.class = "change" Then
        MyVar = TDelement.class.innerText("Value")

    End If
Next
Range("A1").Value = MyVar
appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing


End Sub
```

If I can get a way to set the 'MyVar' variable to the current MTD or YTD value, I'll be done, but I'm having a hard time since there is not a unique identifier for either of these values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently watched some CSS training videos and I can tell you the CSS selector syntax is powerful and I'd recommend it.  This is the same syntax that javascript/web developers use to select elements when using `JQuery`.

I think you should try using

`document.queryselectorall`

or in your case because you have drilled in to the document to get the "performance-chart-table" call `queryselectorall` off of that variable, `TDelements`.

Documentation at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

and you supply as a parameter a CSS selector string the syntax of which can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

And I've gone and done it for you....

```
Sub Get_Change()
    '* Tools-References Microsoft HTML Object Library

    'attempting to scrape Barclay's website

    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim MyVar As String


    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
        .Navigate "http://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-oil-gas-exploration-production-select-industry-index"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
        Range("A1").Value = "Working..."
    Loop
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set htmlDoc = appIE.document

    Dim TDelements2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set TDelements2 = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("performance-chart-table")
    While TDelements2.Length < 1

        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))
        Set TDelements2 = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("performance-chart-table")

    Wend        

    Dim oHTMLTablePerformanceChartTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    Set oHTMLTablePerformanceChartTable = TDelements2.Item(0)


    Dim objChangeCollection As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    Set objChangeCollection = oHTMLTablePerformanceChartTable.querySelectorAll(".change")

    'Debug.Assert objChangeCollection.Length = 2

    Dim objChange2 As Object
    Set objChange2 = objChangeCollection.Item(1)


    MyVar = objChange2.innerText




    'Set TDelements = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("performance-chart-table")
    '
    'For Each TDelement In TDelements
    '    TDelements.querySelectorAll (".change")
    '    If TDelement.class = "change" Then
    '        MyVar = TDelement.class.innerText("Value")
    '
    '    End If
    'Next
    Range("A1").Value = MyVar
    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Wow this is great, thank you! I'm getting a run-time 91 error when I run the code; is there an object I need to select in the references library for it to execute properly?

Comment: Line 34- the one that ends .querySelectorAll(".change"). I've googled, and I don't know for sure how to fix it...

Comment: IE11 Error 91 is the "object variable or With block variable not set" by the way

Comment: Ok I got a 424 error 'Object required' on the first debug.assert line. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks a whole lot for the help by the way... I just started a new job and I'm trying to make a good impression by helping them automate some of the more mundane tasks.

Comment: It says "Automation errorThe object invoked has disconnected" Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks normal. Did you copy and paste the code that is running on your machine, or is it changed in some way?

Comment: The window is open. The error message pops up before the webpage has fully loaded though. Is the DoEvents command not timed with the opening of the page?

Comment: Ok is there a code I can add to keep that from happening?

Comment: Ok, I have added another line.